# page.isvalid vs this.isvalid

Tags: asp.net

Is there any difference between using This.IsValid vs Page.IsValid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page IsValid shows you if whole page is valid
this.IsValid returns information if object and each controls on it is valid.
'this' could be for example user control, so result could be different.

If this.IsValid is false then Page.IsValid is also false, but if this.IsValid is true then you are not sure that Page.IsValid is also true.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. In your webpage's code-behind file, in your webpage's event functions, `this` is getting your actual webpage instance (which inherits Page), and calls it's .IsValid method.

`Page.IsValid()` would be the same as `this.Page.IsValid()`. In this case, Page is getting a reference to the page that the calling control resides in (`this`), which would be the same instance as what I described above. So, in this sense, there's no difference.